# The boundary condition of strong form of a 4th order PDE in a variational problem

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I want to find the strong form of Euler-Lagrange equation of the following variational problem( $\partial\Omega$ smooth ):
$$\min_{u\in H^2(\Omega)} I[u]:=\int_\Omega (\partial_x^2u)^2 + 2(\partial_x\partial_yu)^2+(\partial_y^2u)^2 \,dx\,dy$$

I can get the weak form:
$$\forall v\in H^2(\Omega),\int_\Omega \partial_x^2u\ \partial_x^2v + 2\partial_x\partial_y u\ \partial_x\partial_y v + \partial_y^2u\ \partial_y^2 v \,dx\,dy=0,$$
i.e. $$\int_\Omega \nabla^2 u:\nabla^2v\,dx\,dy=0.$$
By integration by parts,
$$-\int_\Omega div(\nabla^2 u)\cdot \nabla v\,dx\,dy+\int_{\partial\Omega} (\nabla^2u\nabla v)\cdot n\,d\sigma=0$$
($n$ is outward unit vector, and we assume $\nabla v$ is a column vector)
$$\Rightarrow \int_\Omega \Delta^2 u\ v\,dx\,dy - \int_{\partial\Omega} div(\nabla^2 u)\cdot n\ v\,d\sigma+\int_{\partial\Omega} (\nabla^2u\nabla v)\cdot n\,d\sigma=0.$$

Take $v|_\Omega=0,\nabla v|_\Omega=0$ we get $\Delta^2 u=0$; Similarly we get:
$$div(\nabla^2 u)\cdot n=\partial_n(\Delta u)=0\ on\ \partial\Omega.$$
But the last boundary condition is confusing me. What can be implied from "for all $v\in H^2(\Omega),$"
$$\int_{\partial\Omega} (\nabla^2u\nabla v)\cdot n\,d\sigma=0?$$
Apparently it shouldn't be "$\nabla^2 u\ n=0$",since it contains 2 equations, and it times $\nabla v$ which is a gradient instead of an arbituary vector field. Can anyone help with the last boundary condition? Thanks!

Comment: It implies that $n^T \nabla^2 u$ is orthogonal to the space of conservative vector fields on $\partial \Omega$. This isn't actually used as a boundary conditions though. You only consider functions $v$ such that $\nabla v=0$ on the boundary. This is usually done when you choose the space of test functions according to the boundary conditions