# The integral on the boundary equals zero for all functions

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

For region $\Omega$ with smooth boundary, $f$ a vector field smooth enough, if $$\int_{\partial\Omega} \vec{f}\cdot\nabla v=0,\forall v\in H^2(\Omega),$$
then what can we obtain from it about $f$?

This is actually from [The boundary condition of strong form of a 4th order PDE in a variational problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4889518/the-boundary-condition-of-strong-form-of-a-4th-order-pde-in-a-variational-proble) and I don't know how to get the boundary condition. I don't think the above implies $f=0$ on $\partial\Omega$, since $v$ is a gradient and not an arbituary vector field. Can anyone help me with it? Thanks!